# Do I need to use a .htaccess file with GitLab pages?

Tags: .htaccess, gitlab

Do I need to setup a .htaccess file for a hand coded html website on GitLab Pages, also how do I get search engines to index the site?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know gitlab does not support customer server configuration files such as .htaccess or .conf.

You can add your website to the google search engine here: https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/submit-url?continue=/addurl&pli=1

Answer (score 0):

I know this form is old, but it was the first result that appeared in the Brave search engine.

I have tested the 404 error. I have not tested the 403 but according to GitLab's documentation it should work.

Create a file(s), which ever one you want to use or both, called

```
403.html
404.html
```

Place them in the public folder.

EXAMPLE:

```
public/403.html
public/404.html
```

Found this in
[GitLab's Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/pages/introduction.html#custom-error-codes-pages)